# Android downloading .dat file from URL but output is HTML code

Tags: java, android, http, download, android-asynctask

[image: screenshot]

- File should contain "Sample Text"

I'm using Java (Android Studio) to make the application. Using an AsyncTask I'm downloading a .dat file from a URL.

Here is the AsyncTask class

```
private class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/test.dat");
            //OutputStream output = openFileOutput("test.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("DONE!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }

}
```

Permissions are

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If any more information is needed, please reply.

Comment: It will help if you'll post the URL. You can also try to send the server `user agent` string - maybe it cannot identify your 'browser' type.

Comment: It seems the remote website will only show you the content of test.dat if you've `javascript` enabled.

Comment: http://waynetest.byethost14.com/test.dat    
This is the URL I'm using. I really have no clue what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the output that you got, the Web page that you are trying to load requires JavaScript to run. Either you have the wrong URL, or the JavaScript is a key part of generating your desired `.dat` file. I recommend contacting the people who run the site and ask them what the proper way is to get this `.dat` file from something other than a Web browser.

Also note that Android does not have a `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: See also https://wordpress.org/support/topic/it-looks-like-this-is-a-web-page-not-a-feed-i-looked-for-a-feed-associated